# Writing billions of lines to text file in java

Tags: java, performance, programming-challenge, file, file-system

I'm trying to write billions of strings lines to a file, it works for up to 40 million lines, but it's throwing out "java.nio.BufferOverflowException" error for 400 million lines. I also think my solution is slow as it takes 45 seconds to write 40 million lines. Below is the code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

byte[] buffer = "Help I am trapped in a fortune cookie factory\n".getBytes();
int number_of_lines = 400000000;

FileChannel rwChannel = new RandomAccessFile("textfile.txt", "rw").getChannel();
ByteBuffer wrBuf = rwChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, buffer.length * number_of_lines);
for (int i = 0; i < number_of_lines; i++) {
    wrBuf.put(buffer);
}
rwChannel.close();
}
```

How can I make it be faster if possible and also write more than 2 billion lines of string?

Comment: 40M lines * 46 chars = 1.7GB, but 400M lines = 17 GB, and `size` "must be non-negative and no greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`". Do you specifically want memory-mapped I/O, or could you just use `RandomAccessFile.write`?

Comment: @Anonymous I just want to write 2 billion lines of string to a file very fast.

Comment: For *very fast*, can you do it in larger chunks than 46 bytes?

Comment: How to go about it, please?

Comment: You have indicated this is a programming-challenge, could you put the text of the challenge and a link to the challenge in the question?

Comment: Can you assemble a buffer that contains many lines, and then write that buffer all at once? This may be faster than writing one line at a time. But this is off-topic for codereview. Try [a StackOverflow question on this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062113/fastest-way-to-write-huge-data-in-text-file-java). ...why is your code nearly identical to one of the answers there?

Comment: _"45 seconds to write 40 million lines"_ That seems pretty fast. Have you tried increasing the heap size? e.g `-Xms<size>`

Answer (score 2):

It sure sounds like you're running out of memory as you try to build (or allocate) the buffer.

- You need to figure out how big a buffer you can (or want to) use. You'll need to ask the system how much RAM it has, and how much is available, and make your buffer that large.
- You might get a small boost by opening the file as explicitly write-only.
- You'll need to flush the buffer as you go. Something shaped like this psudo-code might work:

```
free = system.free_ram();
use = hungry * free;
buffer = new bytes_buffer_to_file("filename", size=use);
try{
  current_buffer = 0;
  while(line = get_bytes_needing_to_be_written()){
    if(current_buffer + line.length > use){
      buffer.flush();
      current_buffer = 0;
    }
    buffer.append(line);
    current_buffer += line.length;
  }
}
finally{
  buffer.flush();
  buffer.destroy();
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand your code.

Comment: If this was written in C or C++ the file block size would also be important here as well as the disc cache size. The speed can be running into hardware limitations.